# Отображение картинки

Tags: php, img

Есть ссылка вида

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/img.php?img=img.png
```

Естественно при переходе по ссылке никакой картинки нет, а есть редирект на картинку

Как сделать чтобы работало отображение картинки

Что нужно написать в img.php

```
<img src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/img.php?img=img.png" />
```

и главное чтобы не грузило сервер

Адрес картинки известен

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/img/img.png
```

Comment: `imp.php` - в студию!!

Comment: imp.php увеличивает счетчик просмотров в базе и выполняте редирект на http://hashcode.ru/img/img.png

Comment: скинь код сам

Comment: в студию нечего показывать

Comment: `<img src="http://hashcode.ru/url/kartinki/kuda/nuzhno/bylo/redirektit" />`

Comment: Обрисуйте общую картину — что там происходит, и зачем именно через php пропускать трафик, если, вы говорите, он значительный. Ниже видел ваш коммент про то, что обращение к такому php увеличивает счётчик. Это можно оптимизировать, отдавая сразу искомую картинку веб-сервером, записывая обращения к ней в отдельный лог, который потом обрабатывать спец. скриптом раз в сутки.

Answer (score 3):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416753/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) описывал похожую проблему

Раз, по каким-то причинам, нельзя просто указать прямой адрес картинки, лучше сделать, чтобы ссылка выглядела как `http://hashcode.ru/fake_dir_name/img.png`, тогда браузеру будет проще понять как обрабатывать картинку. Я подменил директорию `img` на несуществующий в файловой системе локейшн `fake_dir_name`, чтобы позже обработать на nginx

Будем делать с использованием внутренних редиректов nginx и заголовка X-Accel-Redirect. Такой подход не создает никакой дополнительной нагрузки и даже будет быстрее, чем обычный редирект.
Добавим в nginx

```
location /fake_dir_name {
    #директория будет доступна только при внутренних редиректах
    #если получит от бэкэнда заголовок X-Accel-Redirect
    internal;
}

#преобразует /fake_dir_name/img.png в /img.php?img=img.png
location ~* ^/fake_dir_name/(.*) {
    try_files $uri /img.php?img=$1;
}
```

В img.php

```
$realImageDir = "/img/";
$file = __DIR__ . $realImageDir . $_GET["img"];
//заголовок для внутреннего редиректа
header("X-Accel-Redirect: " . $realImageDir . $_GET["img"]);
//возвращаем Content-Type, чтобы браузер мог корректно обработать файл
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
```

Comment: Добавлю, что в Apache для того же есть **mod_xsendfile**. 
> никакой дополнительной нагрузки
Это вы, мягко говоря, преувеличили. Лучше ли это, чем PHP readfile() это повод для тестов. Если попытаться нарисовать *диаграмму последовательности* для такого запроса, будет очевидно, что x-sendfile требует больше действий, чем отдача файла скриптом. Само же действие чтения-выдачи происходит, вероятно, за близкое время в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 0):

Открывайте на сервере картинку и выдавайте её в php. Не забудте хеадеры соответствующие отправить.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше мнение?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <img src="http://hashcode.ru/img.php?img=img.png" />
> ```
>
> и главное чтобы не грузило сервер Адрес картинки известен
>
> ```
> http://hashcode.ru/img/img.png
> ```

Раз картинка **на том же сервере**, можно её просто прочитать и вывести в выходной поток:

```
$src = $_GET['img'];
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile("img/{$src}");
```

Проверки и очистки оставим в стороне для простоты.

Comment: Будет работать, но при высокой нагрузке значительно нагрузит сервер

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Либо редирект, либо читать и отдавать. Возможно вы переоцениваете нагрузки, такие вещи надо тестировать.  
Учтите и тот факт, что браузеры очень хорошо кешируют картинки, поэтому тот же клиент обратится к этой картинке снова очень нескоро. Вам важны только уникальные клиенты.

Comment: Какие тут чудеса :) internal редирект - стандартное решение для такой задачи. Можно в apache или nginx сделать. Я здесь в ответе описал решение с помощью nginx http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419453/176903. Рекомендую.

Comment: Это вариант "читать и отдавать" ))) Хороший вариант. Не берусь судить насколько X-SendFile превосходит readfile(), т.к. собственно операция чтения выполняется низкоуровневыми фунциями, а не скриптом. А вызов скрипта уже полюбому произошел и весь оверхед от этого мы уже получили.

Comment: Да, про апач трудно сказать, быстрее ли. Но nginx статику отдаст наверняка быстрее.

Answer (score -1):

Способ раз:

```
$bits = file_get_contents('img/img.png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $bits;
```

Способ два, если картинка маленькая, а нагрузка небольшая, [data-uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP):

```
<?php
function data_uri($file, $mime) 
{  
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
  return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
?>

<img src="<?php echo data_uri('img/img.png','image/png'); ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Посещаемость огромная, сервер не выдержит хеадеры
+
размер картинки большой

можно как то сделать редирект с заголовком на кртинку?

ну типа обработал и выдал

header('заголовок png');

//тут какой то код который редиректнул на http://hashcode.ru/img/img.png и выдал картинку

Comment: нагрузки на сервер не должно быть совсем

Comment: можно сделать чтобы картинка в хэше хранилась

Comment: $file = $_GET['img'];
    header('Location: http://hashcode.ru/img/' . $file);

Такая штука вам нужна, что ли? Скрипт всегда будет отдавать только заголовок редиректа, и браузер, по идее, попрётся по новому адресу за картинкой. 

Оптимизировать это можно редиректами в самом веб-сервере. Если только php не выполняет при этом ещё какую-то полезную функцию типа счётчика. Но именно счетчик тоже лучше реализовывать веб-сервером: пусть пишет логи обращения именно к таким картинкам в отдельный лог, а вы раз в сутки этот лог просмотрите и просчитаете отдельным скриптом.