# Проверка прав на скачивание файла (контролируемое скачивание)

Tags: php, nginx

Задача: нужно проверить права пользователя на доступ к файлу. 
Например, при просмотре изображения из приватного фотоальбома, как в Вконтакте. Или, как на моём проекте, нужно проверить куплен ли файл, для того, чтобы скачать его.

Предлагаю такую структуру

```
./
|-- index.php - скрипт для проверки доступа к файлу
`-- secure - директория с приватными файлама
    `-- private.txt - приватный файл
```

Нужно ограничить доступ к файлам из директории secure по критерию, который будет проверяться в index.php.

При этом файл должен быть доступен для определенных пользователей по адресу, типа :

> site.local/files/private.txt

Comment: На этот вопрос можно дать слишком много ответов, либо же качественные ответы будут слишком длинными для данного формата. Пожалуйста, уточните подробности, чтобы сократить количество ответов или выделить проблему, ответ на которую будет занимать пару абзацев.

Comment: Внес уточнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способы решения при использовании php хорошо описаны здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/151795/.
Самый простой способ - использоваь [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php), однако это довольно накладно в плане ресурсов.

Приведу пример решения с использованием nginx и заголовка X-Accel-Redirect.

Допустим, есть следующая структура

```
./
|-- index.php - скрипт для проверки доступа к файлу
`-- secure - директория с приватными файлама
    `-- private.txt - приватный файл
```

Сделаем так, чтобы файл можно было получить по site.local/index.php?path=private.txt, но при этом не был доступен по site.local/secure/private.txt.

Добавим в nginx локейшн

```
location /secure {
    #директория будет доступна только при внутренних редиректах
    #если получит от бэкэнда заголовок X-Accel-Redirect
    internal;
}
```

Вот index.php

```
$secureDir = '/secure/';
//проверяем передано ли имя файла и существует ли файл
//если нет - возвращаем 404 статус
if (
    !isset($_GET["path"]) 
    || empty($_GET["path"]) 
    || !file_exists($file = __DIR__ . $secureDir . $_GET["path"])
){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die('File not found');
}

$path = $_GET["path"]; 

//проверяем права доступа, если нет - 403 статус 
if (!checkAccess($path))
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('403 Forbidden');
}

//заголовок для внутреннего редиректа
header("X-Accel-Redirect: " . $secureDir . $path);
//возвращаем Content-Type, чтобы браузер мог корректно обработать файл
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file));


function checkAccess($path)
{
    //реализация проверки прав доступа
    return true;
}
```

Чтобы сделать ссылки более красивыми, типа site.local/files/private.txt,
  добавим в конфиг nginx

```
#преобразует /files/private.txt в /index.php?path=private.txt
location ~* ^/files/(.*) {
    try_files $uri /index.php?path=$1;
}
```